# jquery draggable connectToSortable keep original

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable

I have the following scenario: I'm writing a simple midi tool, I have 2 lists, the one on the left is sortable and is used to drop the items from the right (left is the list of notes to use and right is the notes I can use). When I drag my note to the left it is removed from the right so i can't add this note again.

How can i stop the original element being removed after the drop? I tried to clone it in the stop event but this created 2 notes on the left and removed from right, I also tried cloning the item in the start event but again when dropped this is removed.

I've not seen any examples for this scenario with most being to add droppable but I'm using sortable, surely this is the same right?

Here is the relevant section of my script:

```
    $(".alloc").draggable(
        {
            connectToSortable: ".playList",
            helper: "clone",
            snap: true,
            refreshPositions: true,
            stack: ".notes",
            handle: ".note-head",
            start: function (_event, ui) {
                let li = ui.helper;
                li.clone().insertAfter(li);
            },
            stop: function (_event, ui) {
                let li = ui.helper;
                let ol = li.parent();
                li.removeClass("bank");
                li.addClass("note");
                let id = li.attr( "id");
                let value = li.attr( "data-value");
                let data = {
                    _token: $('#token').val(),
                    id: id,
                    value: value
                };
                $.post( "/note/add", data )
                    .done( function( result ) {
                        // Update if needed...
                    });

            }
        }
    );

    $(".playList").sortable(
        {
            connectWith: ".notes",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight h-full",
            distance: 4,
            helper: "clone",
            receive: function (_event, ui) {
                ui.item.remove();
            }
        }
    );
```

How do I keep the right list as it is and just clone into the sortable left list?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `ui.item.remove();` from sortable and it worked as required.